# SQL Server - Add signature to stored procedure by certificate does not work

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, permissions, sql-server-2017, certificate

I have a stored procedure in `Database 1` that updates couple of tables in `Database 1` and `Database 2`

To avoid granting calling login/user permissions to do table updates, I would like to use *code signing*

Created certificate in the `master` database, and created login from this certificate
Then I've created users for this certificate-mapped login, in `Database 1` and `Database 2`, and granted them permissions to do table updates

When I tried to run below T-SQL:

```
use [Database 1]
add signature to MyProcedure
by certificate MyCertificate
```

It throws error:

> Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 168
> Cannot find the certificate 'MyCertificate', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Then I try

```
use [master]
add signature to [Database1].[dbo].MyProcedure
by certificate MyCertificate
```

I am in a sysadmin server role, but it throws:

> Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 168
> Cannot alter the object 'Database1.dbo.MyProcedure', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Question:

How can I properly add signature to my stored procedure in `Database 1`, by certificate that is in the `master` database ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to copy the certificate from master to your user database. For example:

```
-- Copy master certificate to user database
USE master;
DECLARE @cert_id int = cert_id('your_certificate')
DECLARE @public_key  varbinary(MAX) = certencoded(@cert_id),
        @private_key varbinary(MAX) =
           certprivatekey(@cert_id,
              'your encryption password',
              'your decryption password')

--these values should not be NULL
SELECT @cert_id, @public_key, @private_key;

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX) =
      'CREATE CERTIFICATE your_certificate
       FROM  BINARY = ' + convert(varchar(MAX), @public_key, 1) + '
       WITH PRIVATE KEY (BINARY = ' +
          convert(varchar(MAX), @private_key, 1) + ',
          DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = ''your encryption password'',
          ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = ''your decryption password'')'

EXEC YourUserDatabase.sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

**EDIT**

If the certificate is encrypted with the database master key instead of a password, omit the decryption password from `CERTPRIVATEKEY` (to decrypt with the source database DBMK) and omit the `ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD` clause of `CREATE CERTIFICATE` (to encrypt with the target database DBMK). The password in this case is used only to encrypt the private key in transit.

```
-- Copy cert to user database
USE master;
DECLARE @cert_id int = cert_id('your_certificate')
DECLARE @public_key  varbinary(MAX) = CERTENCODED(@cert_id),
        @private_key varbinary(MAX) =
           CERTPRIVATEKEY(@cert_id,
              'your encryption password');

--these values should not be NULL
SELECT @cert_id, @public_key, @private_key;

--create certificate in target database encrypted with DBMK
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX) =
      'CREATE CERTIFICATE your_certificate
       FROM  BINARY = ' + convert(varchar(MAX), @public_key, 1) + '
       WITH PRIVATE KEY (BINARY = ' +
          convert(varchar(MAX), @private_key, 1)
        + ', DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = ''your encryption password'');'
PRINT @sql

EXEC YourUserDatabase.sys.sp_executesql @sql;
GO
```

I'll add that for only cross-database permissions, one doesn't need to create a login from the certificate. Create a certificate in a user database, copy the cert to other databases as needed, create a user from the certificate in each database and grant permissions to the cert user, and finally sign the proc with the certificate.

A server level principal is needed only when server-level permissions must be granted.

Comment: thank you @DanGuzman, the answer helped me many times. One thing to note is that I had to change @ sql from nvarchar(max) to varchar(max) recently, as resulting length of the statement was 4259 symbols; while nvarchar(max) seems to allow 4000 max, so statement was cut

Comment: @AlekseyVitsko, [nvarchar(MAX)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#nvarchar---n--max--) should allow roughly 1 billion characters. I wasn't able to reproduce your issue with this script but try casting the concatenated literals as `nvarchar(MAX)` to avoid implicit conversion from `nvarchar(MAX)` to a truncated `nvarchar(n)` value. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73925309/concatenating-sql-server-varcharn-results-with-unexpected-and-inconsistent-tr).